# I want to openTBS for dynamic highlighting of a paragraphs and lines of a docx that I am downloading from my website

Tags: document, docx, opentbs

Haven't found any tips on stack or on the documentation thus far. Any tips? Please note that I'm not using a table for the hightlighting

Answer (score 0):

In Ms Word, the highlighting feature can only apply a limited number of predetermined colors :

- `yellow`, `green`, `cyan`, `magenta`, `blue`
- `red`, `darkBlue`, `darkCyan`, `darkGreen`, `darkMagenta`
- `darkRed`, `darkYellow`, `darkGray`, `lightGray`, `black`
- `none`

The Highlighting is different from the Shading which can apply any background color, including theme's colors. The highlighting color is applied over the shading color if any.

Now, OpenTBS can change any of those properties (highlighting or shading) since it is preexisting in the template. That is OpenTBS cannot create highlighting or shading background, it can only change the color (or turn it to `no color`).

In the DOCX, the XML element for an existing highlighting is placed in head of the highlighted snippet and is like this:

```
<w:highlight w:val="darkRed"/>
```

The XML element for an existing shading is placed in head of the colored snippet and is like this:

```
<w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FF6600"/>
```

So now, the solution for having **dynamic highlighting** with OpenTBS is this :

1. In the template, select the part of text to have the dynamic highlighting, and add any highligh to it.
2. Inside the text, add a TBS tag with the "att" parameter: `[myblock.mycolor_name,att=w:highlight#w:val]`
3. At the PHP side, make sure the column `mycolor_name` have always a value in the list of color given above. This can be assured using a [ondata](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_ondata) custom function.

For having **dynamic shading**, it is quite the same :

1. In the template, select the part of text to have the dynamic shading , and add any color on it. Use only Standard color, not Theme colors, because the XML is a bit different for Theme colors.
2. Inside the text, add a TBS tag with the "att" parameter: `[myblock.mycolor_value,att=w:shd#w:val]`
3. At the PHP side, make sure the column `mycolor_value` have always a value wich is a hexa color value (like in HTML) . This can be assured using a [ondata](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_ondata) custom function.

Comment: Thanks Skrol29, could you please explain how to use the ondata function for this situation?

Comment: @kdeeps Exemple : at PHP side `function f_my_ondata($BlockName,&$CurrRec,$RecNum) { if ($CurrRec['my_column'] == 'ok') $CurrRec['my_color'] = 'yellow'; }`, at template side : `[myblock.my_color,ondata=f_my_ondata;att=w:highlight#w:val]`